# Elastic Search : Get top results according to sum of 3 fields

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

This is my **`QueryDSL`** which returns me top 30 results in descending order according to the sum of field **`count1`**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "2017/08/01",
            "lte": "2017/08/31",
            "format": "yyyy/MM/dd||yyyy||yyyy"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "count1": {
            "gt": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ch_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ChID",
        "size": 30,
        "order": {
          "sum_agg": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "count1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have 2 other fields **`count2`** & **`count3`** too. How to modify this query so that it returns me top 30 documents according to the sum of **`count1`** + **`count2`** + **`count3`**

Answer (score -2):

try to add Top-Hits aggregation as nested aggregation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html